# QStandardItemModel inside Qtableview -- copy content to excell sheet

Tags: qt

I am using `QStandardItemModel` inside `Qtableview` .

Now i want to save the text of the table view to the excel sheet is there some QT class to export the content to excell sheet ?

Or i will have to use some external libraries for it `?`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ExcelFormat library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42504/ExcelFormat-Library) for old excel format (`.xls` files), or something like [LibExcel library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libexcel/) for newer one (`.xlsx` files). There's no classes in Qt for that. I've used ExcelFormat recently, it works fine, can't say anything about other libraries.

Comment: Thanks Spongebobfan, How can i include this external library source code (ExcelFormat_src) inside the QT project so that i can use this library in my project ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Qt class for that purpose. Just loop over all columns and rows and use QStandardItemModel::item(row, column)->text()

Answer (score 0):

if you want to export the selection, you can call `QTableView::selectedIndexes()` or iterate over the whole model and extract the values into a `QString` separated by `'⁄t'` and save it as a file

/edit: do not forget to add the newline to the string ;)